# Angular routeProvider redefine issue

Tags: angularjs, ng-view, route-provider

Is there any way to clear definition of $routeProvider?

This is my [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kdgAnu)

```js
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when("/forums", {
   templateUrl: "hotThread_forums.html",
   controller: "ForumsCtrl"
  })
  .when("/hotThreads/:fid", {
   templateUrl: "hotThreads.html",
   controller: "HotThreadsCtrl"
  })
  .otherwise({
   redirectTo: "/forums"
  });
}]);
```

```js
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when("/forums", {
   templateUrl: "subtitle_forums.html",
   controller: "ForumsCtrl"
  })
  .when("/subtitles/:fid", {
   templateUrl: "subtitles.html",
   controller: "SubtitlesCtrl"
  })
  .otherwise({
   redirectTo: "/forums"
  });
}]);
```

When I click module_1 first time, it works correctly and then click module_2 something wrong.
It seems to be affected by previous definition.
I can't configure routes twice.

So, should I clear previous definition or use other ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First defined your routes, modules, controllers in javascript files. After that i can see that you seems to have different views and controller for similar url.
This is tutorial for route provider.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: I saw.
I create a new module every time, but $routeProvide is singleton,
so it seems to need to clear definition of $routeProvider.


angular.module('myModule', []);  // create a new module
angular.module('myModule');  // retrieve a module

Comment: You can see my plunker demo, module_1 and module_2 has own definition.